# How do I safely lock this property?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, nested

I have partial C# code for a blocking queue that looks like this:

```
private bool flushed;
private object _locker = new object();

public bool Flushed
{
    get { lock (_locker) { return flushed; } }
    set
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            flushed = value;
            Monitor.Pulse(queue);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Monitor.Pulse` method has a `Monitor.Wait` counterpart in the `Dequeue()` method of the blocking queue.

I want to add a method that signals end of data, which checks for the `Flush` condition.  It will look something like this:

```
public bool EndOfData
{
    get { lock (_locker) { return Flushed && (queue.Count == 0); } }
}
```

Here is my question. *Should I call the `Flushed` property as shown in the code above (taking a nested `lock`), or is it sufficient to refer to the private member variable `flushed` directly, as shown below, using only a single lock?*

```
public bool EndOfData
{
    get { lock (_locker) { return flushed && (queue.Count == 0); } }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Mitch: So the only reason to use `Flush` would be to insulate my code from potential logical changes to the `Flush` property itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it makes a difference, personally I would use the nested version.
I think if anything changes in the actual property by using it, `Flushed`, you ensure 
that everything is good to go.

But I truly believe this is a preference call.